# I94 Travel History doesn’t show my departure? Who do I contact?

Tags: usa, esta, i-94

I flew to the US via JFK on the 12th of November and left back to the UK on the 13th, my arrival is shown on the I94 website, but my departure isn’t.

I flew BA, and I’m worried that I’ll be flagged as overstaying despite being back in the UK.

Comment: I just find it strange how my arrival was logged almost automatically, but my departure wasn’t. I don’t remember the CBP officer even looking at my passport on departure, and I had issues with my boarding pass too.

Comment: If you left the US by air, no CBP officer will look at your passport on departure. It is recorded electronically based on information from your airline. If it doesn't show up in a few more days, the [official advice](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/faq) is that you don't need to do anything, but you may want to bring some documentation the next time you come to the US (e.g. boarding pass stub) that you left on time.

Comment: Probably because there is no CBP on departure in the US...

Comment: Would this affect my entry into the US next time? Probably visiting again within the remainder 2016

Comment: @MarkMayo the airline reports the departure to CBP. I don't know how quickly departures are typically reflected in the DB, though. A few days doesn't surprise me at all.

Comment: @phoog that was more in reference to Abacus not remembering it on departure. I get that it gets recorded. :)

Comment: @MarkMayo that makes much more sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please wait for two or three more days and check again. It is very likely to show your departure "in due course" with no action required by you. Meanwhile be sure to retain your boarding card. If after a week there is still no record of your departure see [U.S. Customs and Border Protection](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/752/~/i-still-have-my-i-94) which includes:

> If you departed by a commercial air or sea carrier (airlines or cruise ships), your departure from the U.S. can be independently verified, and it is not necessary to take any further action, although holding on to your outbound (from the U.S.) boarding pass - if you still have it - can help facilitate your reentry next time you come back to the United States.

and:

> If you are a VWP visitor and you left the U.S. by an air or sea carrier, you don't need to worry.

and:

> We strongly urge you to keep a copy of what you send to DHS-CBP and carry it with you the next time you come to the United States in case the CBP Officer has any questions about your eligibility to enter. Carrying those materials with you will also allow your record to be corrected at the time of entry if, for some reason, the London, Kentucky office has not yet done so.