# My sister's passport wasn't stamped when we left the USA - how to rectify?

Tags: visas, usa, passport-stamps, nigerian-citizens

I am Nigerian. My family went on a trip to USA from Nigeria in 2013 and came back together. Recently, my mother applied for another visa and was refused because, according to them, my sister is still in the US. They didn't stamp and acknowledge her exit. How do we rectify this, as it will affect her travel and, apparently, that of my family in the future?

Comment: You can check her i-94 from here https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home. It should have her arrival and departures within the past five years. If it is not recorded you will have to submit evidence like plane tickets, boarding passes, etc things which can confirm she was OUT of the USA by the deadline. The onus is on you to gather overwhelming evidence, then you. You can then submit that evidence by the method and to the address shown here: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/752/~/i-still-have-my-i-94

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I94 Travel History doesn’t show my departure? Who do I contact?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82722/i94-travel-history-doesn-t-show-my-departure-who-do-i-contact)

Comment: The US doesn't stamp passports on exit, so the problem isn't that you're missing a stamp; it's that the US doesn't think she left on time. The links above will allow you to prove that she did.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie The other question seems to only apply to VWP nationals, since the answer is essentially to present yourself at immigration the next time with strong evidence that you left on time. This doesn't apply to non-VWP nationals and it doesn't seem to say anything about visa rejections

Comment: How did your sister Exit teh US? By air or land?

Comment: @DavidRicherby The answer covers it.Read it and the link in the answer. Everything is in there. It covers non-VWP nationals too.

Comment: @DavidRicherby why wouldn't it apply to non-VWP travelers?

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie they don't need to go through all that rigamarole, they can just show the sister's passport with the subsequent entry stamp in whatever country she entered after leaving the US. The evidence need not be submitted to the address in the US, they can submit it to the consulate.

Comment: @phoog Nigerians are not stamped when entering Nigeria. The situation is not as trivial as you make it sound, otherwise they would not have been denied. I was denied a USA visa renewal in 1999 for essentially this same reason. You cannot enter the consulate unless you have a visa appointment. And you cannot email them documents. It is a true catch 22. If she did a new visa appointment in order to show the evidence, she probably wouldn't even get 30 seconds face time from the consular before being denied again. Getting a US visa from my part of the world is not trivial, at all.

Comment: @phoog Because it specifically talks about turning up at the US immigration desks with good evidence that you left the US last time. But a non-VWP national needs to acquire a visa before they can even be allowed on the plane that will get them to the immigration desk. And the exact problem is that they were denied the visa because the US thinks they overstayed.

Comment: @DavidRicherby but presenting evidence to document a departure that the US systems have failed to record is just as necessary for VWP travelers as it is for visa travelers.  Whether the evidence is presented to an officer at the border (for a VWP traveler or one who is reusing a valid visa) or in a consulate (for a fresh visa application) should not make a difference.  Both situtations can possibly be avoided by sending the evidence to Ohio.

Comment: It seems the specific problem is sister's exit was not recorded and that can only be corrected through CBP: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/752/~/i-still-have-my-i-94.  Until then, any interaction with Dept. of State will likely be pointless.

Answer (score 5):

You can check her i-94 from here [i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home). It should have her arrival and departures within the past five years. If it is not recorded you will have to submit evidence like plane tickets, boarding passes, etc things which can confirm she was OUT of the USA by the deadline. The onus is on you to gather overwhelming evidence, then you. You can then submit that evidence by the method and to the address shown here

[I forgot to turn in my I-94 when I left the U.S., what should I do?](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/752/~/i-still-have-my-i-94)

> If you failed to turn in your I-94 Departure Record, please send it,
>   along with any documentation that proves you left the United States. 
>   As of November 1, 2014, the address is:
>
> Coleman Data Solutions
>
> Box 7965
>
> Akron, OH 44306
>
> Attn: NIDPS (I-94)
>
> USA
>
> (If using U.S. Postal Service)
>
> OR
>
> Coleman Data Solutions
>
> 3043 Sanitarium Road, Suite 2
>
> Akron, OH  44312
>
> Attn: NIDPS (I-94)
>
> (If using FedEx or UPS)
>
> **Do not mail your Form I-94 Departure Record or supporting information to any U.S. Consulate or Embassy, to any other CBP Office
>   in the United States, or to any address other than the one above.**
>   Only at this location are we able to make the necessary corrections to
>   CBP records to prevent inconvenience to you in the future. Coleman
>   Data Solutions does not answer correspondence, so please do not ask
>   for confirmation that your record has been updated.
>
> To validate departure, CBP will consider a variety of information,
>   including but not limited to:
>
> Original boarding passes you used to depart another country, such as
>   Canada, if you flew home from there;
>
> Photocopies of entry or departure stamps in your passport indicating
>   entry to another country after you departed the United States (you
>   should copy all passport pages that are not completely blank, and
>   include the biographical page containing your photograph); and
>
> Photocopies of other supporting evidence, such as:
>   Dated pay slips or vouchers from your employer to indicate you worked in another country after you departed the United States,
>
> Dated bank records showing transactions to indicate you were in another country after you left the United States,
>
> School records showing attendance at a school outside the United States to indicate you were in another country after you left the United States
>   , **and**
>
> Dated credit card receipts, showing your name, but, the credit card number deleted, for purchases made after you left the United States to indicate you were in another country after leaving the United States.
>
> To assist us in understanding the situation and correct your records
>   quickly, please include an explanation letter in English. Your
>   statement will not be acceptable without supporting evidence such as
>   noted above. You must mail legible copies or original materials where
>   possible. If you send original materials, you should retain a copy.
>   CBP cannot return original materials after processing.
>
> We strongly urge you to keep a copy of what you send to DHS-CBP and
>   carry it with you the next time you come to the United States in case
>   the CBP Officer has any questions about your eligibility to enter.
>   Carrying those materials with you will also allow your record to be
>   corrected at the time of entry if, for some reason, the London,
>   Kentucky office has not yet done so.