# How soon after departure from the US is I-94 record updated?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, overstaying, i-94

I flew to the US from the UK on 13 March 2022, and came back to the UK yesterday, 21 March. It was on a scheduled flight with BA out of JFK. I’ve just checked my I-94 record online: my arrival into the US is recorded correctly, but my departure from the US to the UK isn’t recorded. How long should I wait before chasing this up and getting USCBP to record the correct date of departure? Is it normal for the record to be updated with a delay?

I’m planning on visiting the US again later in the year and would like to avoid problems.

Update: My departure from NYC has now been recorded, at some point between 24 and 40 hours after the flight.

Comment: How long did it take for your arrival to be recorded? Might be an indicator

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know. I was on holiday so the stamp in my UK passport was all I thought of. Only today did I check the I-94 record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience it takes less than 1 hour when crossing the land border and less than 24 hours when taking a flight. That being said, I wouldn't bother contacting CBP about it if its been less than 1 week since your flight departed.

I don't have any sources to add here as CBP doesn't publish any SLAs around when the I-94 portal is updated, so can only answer from personal experience. If after a week nothing is updated, [see this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/95326/19400) for how to address things with CBP.

Comment: I guess it's a different question but I am genuinely curious: how on earth do you even get the CBP to fix it?

Comment: @chx [My sister's passport wasn't stamped when we left the USA - how to rectify?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/95326/19400) also https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=Coleman+data+solutions

Comment: Thank you. It’s still less than 24 hours since the flight’s departure. I’ll keep an eye on it over the next few days. Meanwhile I’ve taken photos of my boarding passes and baggage tag for an onward flight on 22 March, hoping that I won’t need them.

Comment: @NYCvisitor2228968 From my experience, I'd like to say: Don't worry! Unfortunately, it is also not uncommon that departures are not recorded correctly. This is not a big problem in itself if you can prove that you indeed left the country. *So make sure that you keep your boarding pass* or some printout of it in case you had a digital one.