# I-94 Dates and Locations incorrect

Tags: i-94

I traveled into the US for the first time last year and went onto the I-94 website to get my I-94 number for my K-1 Visa and was surprised to see that there were several arrivals and one departure that I never took. I'm living in Italy and have only entered the US that one time as proven on my passport. I'm not sure why the system would show these arrivals and departures or how I would fix it being overseas right now.

Comment: Two recent questions have addressed correcting an I-94: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94197/my-sisters-passport-wasnt-stamped-when-we-left-the-usa-how-to-rectify/95326#95326 and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82722/i94-travel-history-doesn-t-show-my-departure-who-do-i-contact

Comment: "as proven on my passport": they somehow got additional entries on the same passport number in the database some other way.  A forgery perhaps?  An imposter stealing and using your passport unbeknownst to you? This could be fairly serious.  But how would you -- or they -- know that the passport never crossed the border? Maybe they didn't stamp it (I'm not sure whether VWP visitors are getting stamps these days if they use APC kiosks).